# Convert HTML Path to SVG

Tags: dictionary, svg, path

I've grabbed some code from somewhere to create an interactive UK map using SVG.

You can see it here:

[image]

I'm wondering how I can get the blue area into one big polygon as opposed to separate areas. Any help would seriously appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The "blue area" is England and Wales plus the Isle of Man (the northernmost island just below the grey bit that is Scotland).

Answer (score 0):

You can group the smaller polygon paths like

```
<g id="England">
    <path .... />
    <path .... />
    <path .... />
</g>
```

and then treat them as 1 larger polygon for the purposes of color fill and click area. If you want to remove the inner borders just set the stroke to the same color as the fill.

The only thing you can't do is stroke the outer group since it itself doesn't have a shape, its just the collection of the inner shapes and theres no way to just stroke the edges that do not border another group member. For that you probably would need to actually merge the polygons, which might be easier to do in Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator

See my example here where I've grouped the western US states. Click anywhere in the group to change the color. In the svg(html panel) code, the CA-WA-OR are the last 3 paths at the bottom...

http://jsfiddle.net/webchemist/K9jdD/

Answer (score 0):

Get the original geographic data file in a 'shapefile' or other geospatial data format, load into a GIS package (Quantum GIS is free, open source, and featureful) then do a **polygon dissolve** operation.

You can also do this with the GEOS library which has an interface to C, Python and R if you can program in any of those languages.